# starting a rails app and confused

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

Okay ive read the ruby on rails tutorial book, and i felt like i was learning it. But when i finished i wanna start my own practice project but i cant seem to think of how to start the app.

Are the controller names plural and capitalized?
is a model name singular?
the book showed that the password hashing and stuff was done in a helper file, but i thought that stuff was done in the model?

i just need some direction on how to start the app skeleton i guess

please help!

Comment: If the tutorial you read didn't have you create an app while you were going through it, you should try a different tutorial.

Comment: it was a book, and you did have to create an app. i still dont really understand how to create the app though

Answer (score 1):

what you are probably looking for is:

```
rails new blog
```

creates application skeleton.

it is supposed that you have managed already installing ruby and gem rails

By the way you don't really need any book to start with rails

Just try this awesome official tutorial [getting started Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html).

Cheers1

Comment: nooo. i know all that i mean the part of putting what in what part of the mvc lets say i want to create users

so i do rails generate controller Users then make each action and make a view for each action also i do the routes for each right?

Comment: nope, read article above, or just try running `rails generate model` in shell if hurry )

Answer (score 1):

To get going you need to have ruby and rubygems installed.

Then you must install rails

```
sudo gem install rails
```

Once you have done this Rails will create the app skeleton for you by running this command:

```
rails new your_app_name
```

Then you need to read up to understand how to create basic functionality. The best at first is to use the scaffold and learn from the files created by said scaffold.

```
rails generate scaffold controller_name
```

Don't worry about plural and singular and stuff. Rails scaffold will take care of that.

I recommend you read extensively the official Rails guides. The information is up to date: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

Good luck and enjoy the Rails ride.

Comment: lol. never suggest make a rails scaffold. it is not so good for learning. and on top of that it create everything even stuff you dont need. it will be hard to maintain and read the code that scaffold makes especially or a beginner.

Comment: Based on how your question is phrased (very poorly and full of confusion) I still think this is the best course of action to take. I think it's quite funny that you know so little but have such certainty as to what to do and what not to do. Good luck to you man. I'm off trying to help you now.

Comment: scaffolding is a perflectly good thing to start with, it's good to see how things are done

Answer (score 0):

The main advantage of Ruby on Rails is to build quickly your application. So, for the beginning, use all of the RoR tools. Try this :

```
rails new my_app_name
rails generate scaffold my_model_name field:type field:type
rake db:migrate
rails server
```

And you will be able to start with the skeleton you need. For the division between models and helpers juste remember this : the helpers are for help you to print your informations in the views while the model contains the methods for business logic and dialog with database.

Comment: never suggest someone to use a scaffold. its not good for maintainability or readability.

Comment: I know very good maintainable and readable application wich are initially built with a scaffold. It's a good start for any application if you understand the limits. Of course, when your app will be mature you will never use this command again.